# Why can't I access int with different pointer in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I want to be able to access value with p pointer. But when I use p pointer I'm always getting b variable equal to zero. Please refer to code snippet below.

```
basepointer = malloc(512);      
*((int*)basepointer+32) = 455;  // putting int value in memory  
void *p = basepointer + 32;     // creating other pointer
int a,b;
a = *((int*)basepointer+32);    // 455, retrieving value using basepointer
b = *((int*)p);                 // 0, retrieving value using p
```

Why it happens so? How can I access value with my p pointer?

Comment: Try `*(int *)(basepointer+32) = 455;` in your second line instead. Then go and read about pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @aragaer Not a good idea if `basepointer` has type `void*`.

Comment: What is the type of basepointer?

Comment: Have you tried to debug it?  Look at the values for the different pointers.

Comment: basepointer has (*void) type

Comment: Don't use built-in pointers, `malloc`, `void*` or casts unless you can't solve your [real](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem without them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't find a good duplicate answer, so here's what's going on:

Pointer arithmetic always happens in units of the pointer's base type. That is, when you have `T *ptr` (a pointer to some type `T`), then `ptr + 1` is not the next byte in memory, but the next `T`.

In other words, you can imagine a pointer like a combination of an array and an index:

```
 T *ptr;
 T array[/*some size*/];
 ptr = &array[n];
```

If `ptr` is a pointer to `array[n]` (the nth element), then `ptr + i` is a pointer to `array[n + i]` (the (n+i)th element).

Let's take a look at your code:

```
*((int*)basepointer+32) = 455;
```

Here you're casting `basepointer` to `(int*)`, then adding `32` to it. This gives you the address of the 32nd `int` after `basepointer`. If your platform uses 4 byte ints, then the actual offset is `32 * 4 = 128` bytes. This is where we store `455`.

Then you do

```
void *p = basepointer + 32;
```

This is technically invalid code because `basepointer` is a `void *`, and you can't do arithmetic in terms of `void` because `void` has no size. As an extension, gcc supports this and pretends `void` has size `1`. (But you really shouldn't rely on this: cast to `unsigned char *` if you want bytewise addressing.)

Now `p` is at offset `32` after `basepointer`.

```
a = *((int*)basepointer+32);
```

This repeats the pointer arithmetic from above and retrieves the value from `int` offset 32 (i.e. byte offset `128`), which is still `455`.

```
b = *((int*)p);
```

This retrieves the `int` value stored at byte offset `32` (which would correspond to `int` offset `8` in this example). We never stored anything here, so `b` is essentially garbage (it happens to be `0` on your platform).

---

The smallest change to make this code work as expected is probably

```
void *p = (int *)basepointer + 32;  // use int-wise arithmetic to compute p
```

Answer (score 0):

void pointer arithmetic is illegal in C/C++, GCC allows it as extension.

you need to modify this line:

```
void *p = basepointer + 32;
```

to

```
void *p = basepointer + 32 * sizeof(int);
```

because pointer arithmetic is calculated relatively to the type size.

for example:

if `sizeof (int)  = 4` 
and `sizeof(short) = 2`

and `int *p` has address of `3000`
and `short *sp` has address of `4000`

then `p + 3 = p + 3 * sizeof(int) = 3012`
and `sp + 3 = sp + 3 *sizeof(short) = 4006`

for void it is `1` if the compiler allows it.